# Response body return null when there's actually a value

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I expect the response body to return a value when the status code is not successful because when I try it on Postman it actually gave me a message or one of the attributes of the JSON Array. But, when I try to store the response body into a variable, it always returns null. I don't know why

Here's the `ApiService`

```
@POST("register")
    fun registerAkun(
        @Body registrasiAkun: RegistrasiBodyRequest
    ): Call<RegistrasiResponse>
```

Here's the method inside `RemoteDataSource`

```
override fun registrasiAkun(registrasiAkun: RegistrasiBodyRequest): LiveData<ApiResponse<RegistrasiResponse>> {
        val result = MutableLiveData<ApiResponse<RegistrasiResponse>>()
        result.postValue(ApiResponse.Loading)
        EspressoIdlingResource.increment()

        val client = apiService.registerAkun(registrasiAkun)
        client.enqueue(object : Callback<RegistrasiResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<RegistrasiResponse>,
                response: Response<RegistrasiResponse>
            ) {
                val data = response.body()
                Log.d("RemoteDataSource0", "$data")

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    result.postValue(data?.let {
                        ApiResponse.Success(data)
                    })
                } else {
                    data?.let {
                        result.postValue(ApiResponse.Error(it.message.toString()))
                    } ?: run {
                        Log.d("RemoteDataSource", "$data dan $response")
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<RegistrasiResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("RemoteDataSourceFailure", t.message.toString())
                result.postValue(ApiResponse.Error(t.message.toString()))
            }
        })

        return result
    }
```

Model:

```
data class RegistrasiResponse(

    @SerializedName("message")
    val message: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("customer")
    val customer: CustomerResponse? = null
)
```

```
data class CustomerResponse(
    @field:SerializedName("nama_customer")
    val namaCustomer: String?,

    @field:SerializedName("id_customer")
    val idCustomer: Int?,

    @field:SerializedName("email_customer")
    val emailCustomer: String?
)
```

And here's the Log

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST MY_URL
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 84
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"email_customer":"tesaje@gmail.com","nama_customer":"tesdlu","password":"12345678"}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END POST (84-byte body)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 409 MY_URL (287ms)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.25
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: cache-control: no-cache, private
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-type: application/json
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: vary: Accept-Encoding
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 06:26:48 GMT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: server: LiteSpeed
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46", h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"message":"User Registration Failed!"}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (39-byte body)
D/RemoteDataSource0: null
D/RemoteDataSource: null dan Response{protocol=h2, code=409, message=, url=MY_URL}
```

And here's what
[I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXfAB.png) or  [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtON0.png)

Whenever the response is successful, it returns this

```
RegistrasiResponse(message=Registrasi Sukses, customer=CustomerResponse(namaCustomer=aaaaaa, idCustomer=50, emailCustomer=aaaaa@mail.com))
```

[Postman response success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rWiq.png)

Comment: can you share your POSTMAN response for success and failed ?
then we can get idea about response.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I think not since It's a Firebase(?)

Comment: @Nilesh shared, the failed one is on *I expect* or *these*

Comment: ahh my bad, didn't check, nevermind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should obtain the body from `errorBody()` instead of `body()` for case `!isSuccessful`.

**EDIT:**
You may need an object to hold the `message`. e.g.

```
data class ErrorResponse(
    val message: String? = null
)
```

and inside `onResponse()` will looks like this

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {
    result.postValue(response.body()?.let { 
        ApiResponse.Success(it)
    })
} else {
    response.errorBody()?.string()?.let {
        val error = Gson().fromJson(it, ErrorResponse::class.java)
        result.postValue(ApiResponse.Error(error.message.orEmpty()))
    } ?: run {
        Log.d("RemoteDataSource", "${response.errorBody()?.string()} dan $response")
    }
}
```

Comment: What I want is getting the ```I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"message":"User Registration Failed!"}```. The message of it. Instead of getting value of the message, I'm getting ```D/RemoteDataSource: okhttp3.ResponseBody$Companion$asResponseBody$1@b7f93cf``` base on your solution
```response.errorBody()?.let {
                        Log.d("RemoteDataSource", response.errorBody().toString())
                        result.postValue(ApiResponse.Error(it.toString()))
                    } ```

Comment: You actually can not directly use `response.errorBody().toString()`. You may need an object to use that. I'll update the answer

Comment: Terima kasih banyak ya mas!

Comment: Sip, you're welcome